# Взаимное использование RFID - сканера и QR - code сканера

Tags: java, android

Стоит такая задача: в прогу для промышленных сканеров / терминалов (например, Zebra) помимо считывания RFID меток, добавить возможность считывания QR - кодов. Возможно ли такое совмещение и какие библиотеки можете посоветовать для данной задачи? Может кто знает / использовал примеры для создания проги под считывания QR кода?

Нашел пока что библиотеку MobileVision, хотелось бы узнать, если ли еще дополнительные варианты?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для считывания всевозможных кодов использую эту либу. Удобно и просто. Имеется доступный и понятный Quick start

https://github.com/yuriy-budiyev/code-scanner